# How to save different password for two pages on same domain

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, brave

So I use the same email address to log in on my web-mail and the control panel on my website host page. But I use different password for both actions, the password handler in my browser can only save one password for the website, so the password is overwritten all the time. I have currently used chrome and brave as browsers, are there any way to make any of these two browser treat this to logins as different?

Comment: I think if you use LastPass you can have multiple logins even with the same username. When it tries to enter the passwords automatically it gives you all the possible logins for this url/app and you select the one you think is correct. Not sure if you can do the same on chrome/google passwords.

Comment: It is sad that 2.5 years have passed and chrome still does not support this basic functionality.

Comment: Not just Chrome - Brave, Firefox, etc. #sigh